# How to make await wait for a function to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Recently I have been having an issue with `await` not waiting for a function to finish in a `for ... of` loop. I seem to have poor understanding of what needs to be fulfilled for a `await` to actually wait for a function to fully resolve. This is the code I'm looking at:

```
async function updateFromAllSources(){
    try{
        console.log(appLock)
        if(appLock===1){
            throw 'Application is currently running!'
        }
        appLock = 1;
        const sources = await Source.find({}).exec();
        for(const source of sources){
            console.log(`[LOG] Updating ${source.name}`)
            await updateProductsFromCsv(source)
        }
        appLock = 0;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`[LOG]${e}`)
    }
    
}

async function updateProductsFromCsv(source){
    try{
        const {body} = await got.get(source.url, {
            responseType: 'text',
        });
        let productActive = 0;
        csv(body.trim(), { columns: true, delimiter: source.delimiter }, async (err, records) => {
            for (const [index, element] of records.entries()) {
                if (element['Stock'] > source.minStock) {
                    productActive = 1;
                }
                console.log(`[LOG] Aktualizacja produktu ${index}/${records.length}`);
                io.emit('logging', `Aktualizacja produktu ${index}/${records.length}`);
                await updateProductByName(element['Article number'], { stock: element['Stock'], active: productActive });
            }
        })
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Now: `await updateProductsFromCsv(source)` resolves immediately without waiting for the loop in `updateProductsFromCsv()`, but the same construct used in `updateProductsFromCsv()` where it's supposed to wait for `updateProductByName()` works as expected, the loop waits for the function to be resolved before iterating further.

What's the difference? How do I make the first for loop wait for the function to resolve?

Comment: can you show the definition of your `csv` function ? Or from which library it comes from? In order to await a function, it needs to return a promise. But `updateProductsFromCsv` does not have any `await` - it has a callback style so that's why it's not returning a promise

Comment: @Gonzalo.- ``updateProductsFromCsv`` is an async function so it will return a promise. The problem is ``await`` inside for loop which obviously will not work.

Comment: @SachinSingh No, there is nothing wrong with the `await` inside the loop. The problem is that the promise returned by `updateProductsFromCsv` fulfills too early, because it doesn't wait for the asynchronous callback of the `csv` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your `csv` function call inside `try` block. You are passing a resulting `callback` as an argument and doing `await` inside `for loop` after getting the `records`. The `csv` function call is still going `asynchronously` and control won't wait for that call since there is no explicit `await` for `csv`.

To achieve the desired result, change your `updateProductsFromCsv` as below (Wrap it within `Promise`):

```
async function updateProductsFromCsv(source) {
    try {
        const {body} = await got.get(source.url, {
            responseType: 'text',
        });
        let productActive = 0;
        const records = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            csv(body.trim(), { columns: true, delimiter: source.delimiter }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) reject(err); // Reject incase of error
                else resolve(data);
            });
        });
        for (const [index, element] of records.entries()) {
            if (element['Stock'] > source.minStock) {
                productActive = 1;
            }
            console.log(`[LOG] Aktualizacja produktu ${index}/${records.length}`);
            io.emit('logging', `Aktualizacja produktu ${index}/${records.length}`);
            await updateProductByName(element['Article number'], { stock: element['Stock'], active: productActive });
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You should wrap the `new Promise` *only* about the `csv(…)` call and nothing else, even do the iteration over the records outside of it (after awaiting the promise).

Comment: Hey @Bergi, you are correct. My bad. Will update the answer. Thanks for pointing out the issue

Comment: Hope the updated answer solve the problem. Thanks @Bergi. Will try to be more cautious while posting my answers 

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the error handling - feel free to rollback the edit if you don't like it

Comment: Looks ideal. Thanks for updating it.

Comment: @Bergi this seems alright almost, I havent tried it yet, but doesn't it resolve the promise after taking the records? I want it to resolve after the for loop with updateProductByName

Comment: @Anton There are many promises here that fulfill at different times. The one returned by `updateProductsFromCsv()` will resolve when the body of the function returns, after having `await`ed all the promises created in there.

Comment: @Anton, code iniside `for ... of` loop executes synchronously as per your requirement. There is no need of wrapping whole thing inside `Promise`.

Comment: @PrathapReddy I just don't see how the promise is resolving after the loop, that's the intended behaviour

Comment: Call inside `Promise` alone is not acting as promise in the method. Here is the sequence how it resolves synchronously. 1) got.get (await) call. 2) csv (promise) call. 3) All dynamic promises inside `for ... of` (await `updateProductByName`) based on number of `records` entries. Only after executing all these three steps in same sequence, the function `updateProductsFromCsv` will be resolved. Hope this clear the air for you.

Comment: @PrathapReddy ok that makes it clearer for me. So why did it not work before? Was it because the callback function did not return a promise so the await in the `updateFromAllSources()` thought all the promises were resolved?

Comment: It didn't work with code posted in question because the `csv` function call is not waiting for any thing (no await before `csv`). We are passing only callback not asking it to wait explicitly. In that case the `callback` execution will be moved to `call back queue` and the main `thread` immediately removes `csv` function thinking that it's done and go to the next step after `csv`. Since there is no code after `csv` the `updateProductsFromCsv` will result that it's done. The `event loop` is responsible to bring back the qued items in `call back queue` to `main` thread again at regular intervals

Comment: Feel free to go through [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?vl=en&v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) to understand things explained in my comments even better.